# "I would make sure your future {will/would} be bright" - what is the difference?

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, will-would

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> I would make sure your future **will** be bright.
> I would make sure your future **would** be bright.

I understand that the first would signify conditions as in "If things aligned I would do X". I also know that the first line says that if things did align, I would 100% make your future bright. I am just not sure what the second "would" in the second line would mean.

And is it correct that the usage of dependent clause after a would line is independent of the first would? So like there is no backshift and it's just about what I want to express in that dependent sentence?

Comment: Found a very similar if not the same question here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/280873/107114