# Difference between "difficult to believe that the situation {would/will} return to normal"

Tags: will-would

While reading a newspaper, I found this sentence

> 1. Even if an argument is put forward that many of today's excesses do not reflect long term reality, It is difficult to believe that the situation **would** return to the previous normal.  ([source](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/stamp-out-the-canker-thwarting-democracy/article34257185.ece))

I learnt that **would** is used in hypothetical sentences. What is the hypothetical situation here?? What happens if we use **will** instead of **would** here??

For example:

> 2. Even if an argument is put forward that many of today's excesses do not reflect long term reality, It is difficult to believe that the situation **will** return to the previous normal.

So what is the difference between these two sentences???

Comment: In 1, 'would' invites you to imagine all the hypothetical worlds in which the situation could return to normal, but in 2, 'will' emphasizes the expection that the situation is going to return to normal in the real world.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I don't think he will leave" vs. "I don't think he would leave"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191871/i-dont-think-he-will-leave-vs-i-dont-think-he-would-leave)

Comment: @ColleenV  Sorry, I have seen that already. Eventhough my doubt is similar, I couldn't understand those answers. That's why I posted this new query :)

Comment: Which newspaper?  Please cite (and ideally link) your sources.  I've added a link to show how it can be done.

Comment: The real problem is that you've only quoted half a sentence. At least quote the whole thing:  "Even if an argument is put forward that many of today’s excesses do not reflect long-term reality, it is difficult to believe that the situation would return to the previous normal. "

Comment: If the answers of the suggested duplicate are not helpful, you should edit your question to explain why they didn't help you, or what you don't understand about them.

Comment: @JamesK It's from an Indian newspaper called "The Hindu". The article is only for subscribers. Otherwise I would have provided the link. And thank you for suggesting me to add the entire sentence. I edited it now

Comment: @JamesK  So by any chance "Even if an argument is put forward that many of today's excesses do not reflect long term reality" is the imagined hypothetical situation???

Comment: [suggest x to me, not suggest me x]

Comment: I think the original sentence should have been written maybe as "Even if an argument WERE put forward that many of today's excesses do not reflect long term reality, It is difficult to believe that the situation would return to the previous normal." I think the mood is the "future unreal conditional". The use of "will" is not appropriate as it doesn't convey the unreality of the situation the reader is attempting to convey.

Comment: @rocket_boomerang_19  If "WERE" is used and made it  hypothetical, Doesn't it become " It WOULD BE difficult for me that the situation would return to the previous normal" ?

Comment: yeah. that also. correct

Answer (score 0):

> It **is** difficult to believe that the situation **would** return to the previous normal.

It may be that the rules for Indian English are different, but I (UK English) can't think of any justification for using **is** in the main clause and **would** in the that-clause.

If you were to say that it is talking about a hypothetical situation predicated on the first part of the sentence, you would have to use **would be** instead of **is**. The complete sentence would be:

> Even if an argument **were** put forward that many of today's excesses do not reflect long term reality, It **would be** difficult to believe that the situation **will** return to the previous normal.

Answer (score -1):

One's past tense:

It WAS difficult to believe it WOULD return to normal

You should add WAS there.

The other's future tense and is grammatically correct.

EDIT: Also, it's learned, not learnt. It just bugs me.

Comment: Learnt is perfectly acceptable in the UK. Please do your research before stating your opinions.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/learn https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/learnt